# read audio files and send them by SPDIF

Tags: pcb

Can these chip read audio files from an SD card/USB flash drive and generate an SPDIF digital stereo audio output?

[VS1053](http://www.vlsi.fi/en/products/vs1053.html) or [VS1063a](http://www.vlsi.fi/fileadmin/datasheets/vs1063ds.pdf)  or [PCM2906](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm2906.pdf)

EDIT: I think this is the [DEVICE](https://www.newbecca.com/product/530359651137) I need. SD card / USB host / Bluetooth SPDIF output

Comment: okay you can delete it

Comment: rather than ask what IC ask how does one interface Digital Audio to TOSLINK?

Comment: I apologize if I was not clear, it is difficult to explain in English for me. I wanted to say that I would like to build a simple PCB to play audio files wav / flac from SDcard or usb flash drive and convert them to spdif output. Something like a converter from USB flash stick to spdif, so I could connect to my external dac.

Comment: @asterix There are a LOT of things that need to happen to play an audio file.  It's by no means simple.  Each step has it's own complexities and interdependent decisions: [reading the physical storage media] [understanding the filesystem to find the data] [interpreting that data as something useful] [sending it out in a way that the next thing finds easy to understand].  Of course every step also requires error-checking so that you don't spew out garbage but tell the user why you can't do your job.  You're probably best off to use a Raspberry Pi and your favorite open-source jukebox app.

Comment: after investigating a few days I came to the conclusion that it is easier to buy a device.  I found one.  Doing it myself requires a lot of knowledge, but there are SOC chip that do it all. But now I prefer to buy https://es.aliexpress.com/item/-/33053435389.html

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a good chip but TOSLINK is just a serial NRZ data link that requires a TOSLINK IC from Toshiba or equiv. [TODX2850A](http://www.toshiba.com/taec/cgi-bin/display.cgi?table=Category&CategoryID=7071) using PCM data.

SPDIF is the wired NRZ PCM signal.

> You must have a very specific SPDIF digital cable. While a SPDIF coaxial connection looks like an RCA analog type connection, it is not the same. SPDIF is a stereo digital connection

For PCM Audio all you need a CABLE, 24”  SPDIF DIGITAL & CD AUDIO or equiv. To design your own PCB, you start with a list of all interface specs and protocols for compressed digital audio then a block diagram. Your request is too big. Go buy one.

HOW TO [convert](https://youtu.be/xs7wyb5pFoo) video. Use different digital cables to suit your source.

**Consider a Raspberry Pi with Flash USB input to analog audio out** or to your DAC as a serial data stream.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/tinkernut-diy-pi-zero-audio/

### Last consideration

https://achanmix.blogspot.com/2018/03/ea-bt4hs_92.html

> • ATS250X is a third generation single-chip highly-integrated digital music system solution for devices such as dedicated audio Boombox and player. It includes a high performance DSP with embedded RAM and ROM, ADPCM record capabilities and USB interface for downloading music and uploading voice recordings.
>
> • ATS250X also provides an interface to SPDIF, Nor flash memory, LED/LCD/LCM, button and switch inputs, headphones, and microphone, and FM radio input and control. It supports MP3, WMA and other digital audio standards. For devices like USB-Disk, it can act as a USB mass storage and slave device to personal computer system. The Chip has low power consumption to allow long battery life and an efficient flexible on-chip DC-DC converter that allows many different battery configurations, including 1xAA, 1xAAA and Li-on. The built-in Sigma-Delta D/A includes a headphone driver to directly drive low impedance headphones. The A/D
>
> • includes inputs for both Microphone and Analog Audio in to support voice recording and FM radio integration features. Thus, it provides a true ’ALL-IN-ONE’ solution that is ideally suited for highly optimized digital audio  Boombox and player.

```
• Support WMA Decoder and Other Digital Audio Standards
    • Digital Voice Recording (ADPCM）
    • On-chip DSP , integrated MCU with DSU
    • External SPI Nor flash
    • Support the following memory card interface
      - Secure Digital Card Specification Version 2.0(1/4-bit mode)
      - Memory Stick Version 1.43(1/4-bit mode)
      - Memory Stick Pro Version 1.02(1/4-bit mode)
      - Memory Stick Pro-HG Version 1.01(1/4/8-bit mode)
    • Support 24MHz OSC with on-chip PLL for MCU and about 32KHz RC oscillator
    • 2-channel DMA,1-channel CTC and interrupt controller for MCU
    • Energy saving with dynamic power management, supporting 1xAA, 1xAAA and Li-on battery. 
    • Build in Stereo 20-bit Sigma-Delta D/A
    • Enough GPIOs For all applications
    • Support TWI/SPI/UART/IRC/SPDIF interface
    • Support external 8080 Series LCM driver interface
    • Support FM Radio input and 41 levels volume control
    • Support Stereo 21-bit Sigma-Delta A/D for Microphone/FM Input, sample rate at 8/12/16/22/24/32/48KHz
    • D/A+PA SNR :without A weight>91dB
    • A/D SNR >90dB ,support Difference/2-channle Microphone
    • Headphone driver output 2x20Mw @16ohm
    • Standby Leakage Current: <50uA
    • Low Power Consumption: <40mW@VDD=1.6V at typical Audio decoder solution
```

Comment: I do not know how to call it, but I just need to know if there is an IC chip that allows me to create a PCB that has an  SDcard / USB flash drive  input and SPDIF optical / coaxial output

Comment: D: so complex using raspberry pi. What about use ATS2825 Bluetooth Module SPEC + PE-65612 ? I guess I dont need RPi in this case ? It has usb device/ sd card

Comment: Sure https://achanmix.blogspot.com/2018/03/ea-bt4hs_92.html

Comment: It is complex to make myself, I will buy this Device https://es.aliexpress.com/item/-/33053435389.html. sorry for that